# PHP function to get greatest result from given vars

Tags: php, comparison

Did a quick google search, but couldn't find anything useful, maybe wrong keywords, dunno.

Is there a function or anything in PHP that can return greatest value from provided ones?

Like - `greatest($var1, $var2 [, $var3])` and it would return the largest/highest/greatest value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is precisely what PHP's [max](http://www.php.net/max) function does.

(Isn't it *great* when that happens.)

Comment: Thanks! And.. Never heard of it before :O

Comment: Great, for who?  :) Have a +1 anyway

Comment: @Steve Great for whoever needs the function. :-)

Comment: @middaparka - Yep I know. I was just talking about the rep-without-effort kind of great.  I was a few seconds late.  :/

Comment: @Steve Yup, sometimes it's your turn to be the early bird. :-)

Comment: @middaparka - LOL and yes, that is great!